# web.config changes for KB3159706

Tags: powershell, scripting, web-config

i spent a few hours trying to code this by myself, but i don't know much about editing the web.config and all the examples i found don't come close to what i need. CHANGE#1 is unique because it does include the typical key=value.

I want to be able to script (PowerShell) the required modifications of Web.Config, only if the values do not already exist.

**CHANGE#1:**

Onsert this 
(if not already there and "true"): `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"`

```xml
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

**CHANGE#2:**

Insert this if not already there:

```xml
<endpoint address=""                        
  binding="basicHttpBinding"
  bindingConfiguration="SSL"
  contract="Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.IClientWebService" />
<endpoint address="secured"
  binding="basicHttpBinding"
  bindingConfiguration="SSL"
  contract="Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.IClientWebService" />
```

It goes between here:

```xml
<services>
  <service
    name="Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.Client"
    behaviorConfiguration="ClientWebServiceBehaviour">
    <!-- ... CODE FROM CHANGE#2 GOES HERE ... -->
  </service>
</services>
```

This is the code so far for change#1 (not working):

```bsh
$sWSUSwebConfig = "C:\Program Files\Update Services\WebServices\ClientWebService\Web.Config"
$xFileContent = [Xml](Get-Content $sWSUSwebConfig)
$root = $xFileContent.get_DocumentElement()
foreach ($item in $root."system.serviceModel"."serviceHostingEnvironment") {
  if ($item."multipleSiteBindingsEnabled" -ine "true") {
    $activeConnection = $root.serviceHostingEnvironment
    $activeConnection.SetAttribute("multipleSiteBindingsEnabled", "true")
    #$item.add."multipleSiteBindingsEnabled" = "true"
    $iKeyFound = $true
  }
}
$xFileContent.Save("c:\temp\web.config")
```

Reference for modifications: step 3 from [kb3159706](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3159706).

Comment: "*not working*" -> [ask].  Not working ... how?

Comment: @nerf (welcome to SO!) - Please provide what error message(s) youre receiving for better support on what your issue is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.